# How do you make a non-elevated view appear infront of an elevated view?

Tags: android

As you may know, android draws views with higher elevation on front. Is there any way to override this behaviour ? I have two sibling views in a layout, A and B. view A has 0 elevation and view B has 2dp elevation. If these two views overlap, view A should appear in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A easy work around which I commonly use is, setting the elevation the view on top of the other increased by 1dp.

Example:

```
<view
    android:id = "@+id/A"
    elevation = "3dp"/>

<view
    android:id = "@+id/B"
    elevation = "2dp"/>
```

It works great and doesn't leave any shadow too.

Comment: Oh I didn't think this simple workaround would work. Thanks, will try it now.

Comment: I the answer is correct accept it as a correct answer.